# How can I make a function that fetches row

Tags: php

So I want to make a function where I can fetch data like the following

```
$user->userData('username');
```

Here is my current function

```
public function userData() {
    $username = "username";
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $query->execute(['username' => $username]);
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   return $row;

   }
```

the problem is that It's returning this error when I call the function:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php/home.php on line 9 Arrays
```

Line 9 is

```
echo $user->userData('username');
```

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: Edited the post, included the error.

Comment: But you are printing an array as a string, you should use `print_r` to print array data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` function prints strings.
Array returned by your function is not a string (definitely).
So, php tries to convert array to string and warns you about it.

If you want to print values that are not string - use `printr_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => alam [email] => me@alam.com [password] => pass ) )  it printed this, what would I have to do so I can just print the row that  I want?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it the row you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90121/discussion-between-alam-and-u-mulder).